# How I can mock mongodb find when a variable hold the mongoclient

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pyramid

I am trying to mock the return of db.collection.find to avoid database calls. I tried to create a mock.patch for mongoclient() and attached on it a return_value. But when my_call() call db.collection.find it just return a Mock Object. Somebody have a idea how mock it?

```
#dao.py
class MyDao():

    def my_call():
        db = mongoclient().db_name
        result = db.collection.find()
        return result


#test_dao.py
import dao

def test_my_call():
    result = dao.my_call()
    assert result == list()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help to see your current mock to edit. In general, this is how I would mock the pymongo `collection.find()` as a standalone function.

## test_dao.py

```
import unittest
import mock
from mock import Mock
import pymongo

class Test_Dao(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Set up the mock
    """
    @classmethod
    @mock.patch('pymongo.collection')
    def setUpClass(self, mock_mongo):
        a = Mock()
        a.find.side_effect = self.findResponse      # Assign side effect for mocked method
        mock_mongo.return_value = a                 # Importing pymongo.collection returns the mock

    """
    Response Data
    """
    findResponse = 'some data'

    def test_my_call():
        result = dao.my_call()
        assert result == list()

   ...
```

In your case that is worth a try but might not work because you are calling collection.find() from a variable.

You may need to mock the MongoClient() such that `db_name` has a `side_effect` to return a fake class. Then the fake class would need a collection.find() method you define. That would be a little longer and look a little bit like this:

```
class FakeCollection:
   def find:
      return 'data'

class FakeDatabase:
   def collection:
      return FakeCollection()
...

@classmethod
@mock.patch('pymongo.MongoClient')
def setUpClass(self, mock_mongo):
    a = Mock()
    a.db_name.side_effect = self.dbResponse
    mock_mongo.return_value = a

dbResponse = FakeDatabase()
```